# Проблема при установке PlayOnLinux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

при попытке добавить репозиторий, выбрасывает ошибку. У меня ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'
```

ошибка

```
W: Ошибка GPG: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: 

Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: Репозиторий «https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease» не подписан.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
W: Ошибка GPG: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: Репозиторий «https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease» не подписан.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
W: Ошибка GPG: http://dl.bintray.com/dawidd6/neofetch jessie Release: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 379CE192D401AB61
E: Репозиторий «http://dl.bintray.com/dawidd6/neofetch jessie Release» не подписан.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не выполнили загрузку и добавление ключа подписи репозитория

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main'
```

Comment: Не сразу досмотрел, вы попробовали добавить репозиторий для Ubuntu 16/04, если же вы используете Ubuntu 18/04 нужно добавить соответствующий репозиторий. Внес изменения в ответ